# website returns 501 when trying to log in with python

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm talking about this website:

http://www.belegger.nl/mijnbelegger/voorpagina

I'm trying to log in as follows:

```
def login(self, username, password):
    #form_doc: a lxml.html object
    form_doc = self.browser.getdoc("http://www.belegger.nl/mijnbelegger/voorpagina")
    form_html = form_doc.cssselect("div.loginPanel form")[0]
    form_dict = {inp.get('name') : inp.get('value') for inp in form_html.cssselect("input")}
    form_dict['username'] = username
    form_dict['password'] = password

    #form_dict now contains all the correct inputs and their values

    #then, i precisely copy all the headers of a successful browser login:
    self.add_headers()        

    #what follows is a POST request:
    self.browser.open("http://www.belegger.nl/mijnbelegger/voorpagina", self.browser.urlencode(form_dict))

def add_headers(self):
    headers = {
        'Host' : 'www.belegger.nl',
        'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0',
        'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language' : 'en-gb,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
        'Referer' : 'http://www.belegger.nl/mijnbelegger/profiel',
        'Content-Length' : '187',
        'Content-Type' : 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
        'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
        'Pragma' : 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'
    }
    for header in headers.items():
        self.browser.opener.addheaders.append(header)
```

And here's the resulting request:

```
POST /mijnbelegger/voorpagina HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 115
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
Host: www.belegger.nl
Referer: http://www.belegger.nl/mijnbelegger/profiel
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

formtoken=c5851960db739b61bc28afd4f23cec2badacb807&username=xxx&password=xxx&Inloggen=Inloggen
```

The request in python is almost exactly similar to the request in firefox, the only difference is the 'connection' header, which doesn't seem to be changeable via urllib2.

But there's more:

if i try to redo a successful login using the firefox addon 'live http headers', i get the same 501 error. I even get this when i use a correct 'formtoken' value.

So, what could be the cause of this 501?

Comment: I see 2 different content-type values, is it correct?

Comment: this is what firebug says:

Request Headers From Upload Stream:
Content-Length : 115, 
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I don't know what 'from upload stream' means but i am assuming it is correct

Comment: yes, in the request headers content type is text/plain, I was wondering why firebug says application/x-www-urlencoded...what's that? and content-length?